# Convert key to item with laravel collections

Tags: laravel, collections

```
[
  "bob" => $books
  "maria" => $otherBooks
]
```

to

```
[
  [
    name => "bob"
    data => $books
  ],
  [
    name => "maria"
    data =>  $otherBooks
  ]
]
```

Comment: the myitem value, has that any relations to anything, how can i determine that value? If i have collection of posts, how can i get to the point of knowing the key should be "posts"?

Comment: check this one https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: changed the example because it is not clearer sorry for that

Comment: @Juliatzin I've added a solution. Let me know if I understood the question wrong. If so, then I'll update it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize `map`, map takes `$item` and `$key` there is your input arrays key value, as the argument for the closure. If you map those to expected array structure this should work.

```
$result = collect([
  'bob' => $books
  'maria' => $otherBooks
])->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return [
        'name' => $key,
        'data' => $item,
    ]
});
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: this will give a collection with 'bob' and 'maria' as keys so to achieve an array as in the question maybe converting results to array and getting the array values would be good? As in: `array_values($result ->toArray())`

Comment: I guess I forgot I could use $key param inside map() ! Thanks

Comment: "this will give a collection with 'bob' and 'maria' as keys" no this will give an array like so [['name' => 'maria', $data => $yourItems]]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with collections.

```
collect([
  "bob" => $books
  "maria" => $otherBooks
])->map(function ($books, $name) {
    return [
        'name' => $name,
        'data' => $books
    ];
});
```